# Computing stats info for the entire year from a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a data frame (similar to the one below) which roughly accounts for a year.
[image]

..

..

..

[image]

The first column is info related date, second column is a code for identifying a particular item. May I know how to perform/get mean, median, mode etc related stats info for the entire year.

[A MWE of the data can be found here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YfYJdRcrv3bUQs5L0U6GJgIhO89wmOpl/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "entire year" - i.e., what are the start and end dates but try `df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.year)[df.columns[2:]].agg(['mean', 'median'])`

Comment: @It_is_Chris that’s a lovely one-liner. I did not know it was possible to add the groupby argument like so. (I would have added a “year” column prior to the groupby function hence wasting a line.)

Comment: Thank you @It_is_Chris :-) my problem got solved with 
`df.groupby(df['EN'])[df.columns[2:]].agg(['mean', 'median'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @it_is_Chris, the problem got solved:

> df.groupby(df['EN'])[df.columns[2:]].agg(['mean', 'median'])